# how to check for file with wildcards existance in while loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I'm writing a bash shell script where I want to implement a sleep sequence as long as a file exists. Now, in the simplest case this is something like:

```
while [ -f fileName ]
do
echo "waiting"
sleep 1
done
```

Now, in my situation the first issue is the following: I want to use wildcards in the fileName. This can be resolved by something like:

```
fileName="$path/$prefix*$suffix" 
while [ -f $fileName ]
    do
    echo "waiting"
    sleep 1
done
```

However, this fails if more than one file matching the fileName

```
./testWait.sh: line 11: [: /home/nrc11/egsnrc/BEAM_TB_jaws/130318110457_s.lock: binary operator expected
```

how do I resolve this?

Here is the (semi) specific example:

```
#!/bin/bash -u

timeStamp="130318110457"
echo "prefix of files: $timeStamp"

beamDir=$(awk '{ print $0 }' $timeStamp/$timeStamp.beamDir)
file="$EGS_HOME$beamDir/$timeStamp*.lock" 

echo $file

while [ -f $file ]
do
    echo "waiting"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: What should be tested? Whether all files exist? Any exist? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` on the expanded wildcard to verify that it returns something else than an asterisk after the time stamp:

```
while echo $file | grep "^$EGS_HOME$beamDir/$timeStamp"'[^*]' ; do
    echo "Waiting..."
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Did not consider using grep at all, but seems to work just fine. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am very user about this, I trying doing this long back, I used some thing called inotify, a package in linux, try it out, it actually makes your life more easier.

Comment: can you please clarify your answer. What is inotify and how does it help solve the question?